# ImageViews and TextViews in Relative Layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I was wondering if anyone could explain a small problem i'm having. I'm trying to get my head around RelativeLayouts and have the following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >        

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/newsImage"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="#ffffff"  >
            </ImageView>            

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/newsSubtitle"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:textColor="#0098bf"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/newsImage"
                android:textSize="18sp">
            </TextView>  

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/newsId"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:textSize="0sp"  >
            </TextView>     
</RelativeLayout>
```

As i understand it in RelativeLayouts you can align children to the parent (RelativeLayout) using 'alignParentLeft="true"', and you can align each child to other children using alignRight="@+id/childId". This seems to work well enough with TextViews, however i'm having trouble getting my ImageViews to behave properly - it's like they don't actually seem to take up any space, as the TextView just sits on top of the image instead of aligning to the right of the image.

Am i misunderstanding something here or do RelativeLayouts have a different way of aligning Image / Text combinations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call android:layout_below="@id/idofImageView" on your textview and add an image to the ImageView.

Edit: Sorry you want it to the right: `android:align_toRightOf="@id/ImagevIEW"`

Comment: I have done that within the TextView 
'android:layout_alignRight="@+id/newsImage"'

I also tried removing the + sign, but that didnt work either.

Comment: the + sign means you are creating a new id when you want to call the existing one. In the future don't use the plus when referencing another view. If the image is big the textview will overlap it but the code may still work. Try it with ic_launcher(app icon) as the source of your imageview to test.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >        

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/newsImage"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="#ffffff"  >
            </ImageView>  

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/newsId"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:textSize="0sp"  >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/newsSubtitle"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textColor="#0098bf"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i tried layout_height="wrap_content" and layout_height="match_parent", and they both give the same result - textview sitting on top of imageview :/

Comment: Try with some dp like android:layout_height="100dp" or else with wrap content `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: Okay, so exactly how do you want your content. you want to show text-view exactly below of your image view or above.

Comment: I have updated my answer please have a look. This is exactly what you are  looking for or still you need some change...

Comment: thank you for your help, it turns out i was referencing the ImageView wrong and calling alignRight instead of toRightOf. again thank you for your help!